# Java - Use Return Value as Parameter in another Method - Memory Management

Tags: java, memory-management

Considering internal memory usage

```
input = web_service.FullCompanyListChunksGet(x, ChunkSize);
ReadXML(input);
```

should take the same memory as

```
ReadXML(web_service.FullCompanyListChunksGet(x, ChunkSize));
```

Doesn't it? Do both samples pass just the reference to the ReadXML Method?

Please help me understanding the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd expect the JITted code to be pretty much the same. In the bytecode there's an extra store/load for the first form, but I'd be *very* surprised to see that make a real difference. The advantage of the first form is that it can make debugging easier - but it makes the code more verbose at the same time.

EDIT: I originally wrote that the two create the same bytecode, but that's not true:

```
public class Test {
  static void separate() {
    String x = "hello";
    String y = x.toString();
    foo(y);
  }

  static void combined() {
    String x = "hello";
    foo(x.toString());
  }

  static void foo(String x) {
  }
}
```

Compiles to (just the `separate` and `combined` methods):

```
static void combined();
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String hello
   2:   astore_0
   3:   aload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   7:   invokestatic    #4; //Method foo:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   10:  return

static void separate();
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String hello
   2:   astore_0
   3:   aload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   invokestatic    #4; //Method foo:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: @shambleh: Sometimes - sometimes not. I certainly wouldn't want to *always* create a local variable for *every* intermediate value. Sometimes the name of the variable can help though, as well as the debugging bit.

Comment: Does  7:   astore_1  8:   aload_1 mean that a temporarily copy is created?

Comment: Well, it does in the bytecode, but I'd expect the same JITted code. If it takes any more memory *at all* (which I doubt) it'll only be 4 or 8 bytes - enough for the reference. It's not creating a copy of the *string*.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example

```
input = web_service.FullCompanyListChunksGet(x, ChunkSize);
ReadXML(input);
```

the variable input remains in scope until the end of the block that contains this code. It's not eligible for GC until the exit of that block. In this example

```
ReadXML(web_service.FullCompanyListChunksGet(x, ChunkSize));
```

the variable goes out of scope at the function return, so is eligible for garbage collection earlier.

Comment: Is the JIT not allowed to notice that the variable won't be used any more, and (when not running under a debugger) ignore it as a root earlier?

Comment: @Jon: I think it is, but if it really, really matters (!?!) that a data structure is garbage collected earlier, not assigning it (or nulling it afterwards) means that you don't have to depend on the JIT's behaviour on a particular platform.

Comment: @rAyt: in my experience it is very unusual for something like this to make much difference in practice.  I'd only resort to micro-managing references in stack frames if I had HARD evidence that it was causing problems.  If you don't have evidence then this is probably a premature optimization and a waste of your time.